# How to compare HH:MM in C#

Tags: c#

Hi I have to compare HH:MM(hour and minutes). How can i do so?

```
var t1 = DateTime.Now.ToString("HH:mm");
var t2 = "20:03";
var res =result(t1, t2);

public int result(string t1, string t2)
        {
            int i = -1;

            int hr1 = Convert.ToInt32(t1.Split(':')[0]);
            int hr2 = Convert.ToInt32(t2.Split(':')[0]);

            int min1 = Convert.ToInt32(t1.Split(':')[1]);
            int min2 = Convert.ToInt32(t2.Split(':')[1]);

            if (hr2 >= hr1)
            {
                if (min2 >= min1)
                {
                    i = 1;
                }
            }

            return i;
        }
```

But it is not correct.. it is not taking care of all conditions.. how to make it perfect. Or is there any built in function that does this with thsi input only(I checked but no answer).

Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you looked at `TimeSpan`? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan.aspx

Comment: You can create two DateTime objects and compare them. Then either use framework to compare dates or >< signs

Comment: What conditions does it not take care of?

Comment: Convert to DateTime, there is a TimeOfDay property containing a `TimeSpan`...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a [TimeSpan](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/269ew577.aspx):

```
TimeSpan s1 = TimeSpan.Parse(t1);
TimeSpan s2 = TimeSpan.Parse(t2);
return s1.CompareTo(s2);
```

If you're not sure the inputs are in the correct format, you can use [TryParse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan.tryparse.aspx) instead.

Answer (score 7):

If you can assume the two strings are already in the right format, just use:

```
return t1.CompareTo(t2);
```

After all, they're lexicographically sorted due to the format used - no need to parse :)

With all the references to `TimeSpan`... Of course if you were using [Noda Time](http://noda-time.googlecode.com) you could use:

```
private static readonly LocalTimePattern TimePattern = 
     LocalTimePattern.CreateWithInvariantInfo("HH:mm");

...

public int CompareTimes(string t1, string t2)
{
    // These will throw if the values are invalid. Use TryGetValue
    // or the Success property to check first...
    LocalTime time1 = TimePattern.Parse(t1).Value;
    LocalTime time2 = TimePattern.Parse(t2).Value;
    return time1.CompareTo(time2);
}
```

(You can use `TimeSpan` if you want, of course... but `LocalTime` represents the actual type of data you've got: a time of day, rather than an amount of time passing ;)

Comment: Good if the data has perfectly consistent format.  Otherwise, e.g. `"4:30".CompareTo("20:00")` won't work right.

Comment: @BenVoigt: No, there are other problems with the existing code. I just haven't focused on them as it's so simple to get it right if we assume that the values *are* okay :)

Comment: Yeah, I just noticed that too.

Answer (score 0):

If these represent clock times (i.e. hour is always less than 24), then [`DateTime.ParseExact`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w2sa9yss.aspx) is what you want.

Otherwise, [`TimeSpan.ParseExact`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd992370.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

If you can guarantee that the provided time is always HH:mm you can use `TimeSpan.ParseExact`.

Answer (score 0):

You can parse the time direct from the string. Beware the culture!

```
 var time1 = DateTime.ParseExact("12:56", "hh:mm", CultureInfo.CurrentCulture);
 var time2 = DateTime.ParseExact("11:21", "hh:mm", CultureInfo.CurrentCulture);
```

Answer (score 0):

**The other solutions are more elegant and simple and deal with culture issues and should be used in professional level code.**

But to fix your code, you only need to compare the minute values if and only if the hour values are equal.

```
var t1 = DateTime.Now.ToString("HH:mm"); 
   var t2 = "20:03"; 
   var res =result(t1, t2); 

   public int result(string t1, string t2) 
        { 
            int i = -1; 

            int hr1 = Convert.ToInt32(t1.Split(':')[0]); 
            int hr2 = Convert.ToInt32(t2.Split(':')[0]); 

            int min1 = Convert.ToInt32(t1.Split(':')[1]); 
            int min2 = Convert.ToInt32(t2.Split(':')[1]); 

            if (hr2 > hr1)
               i = 1;
            else if (hr2 = hr1 && min2 >= min1) 
               i = 1; 

            return i; 
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

This works

```
public int CompareTime(string t1, string t2)
        {

            int i = -1;

            int hr1 = Convert.ToInt32(t1.Split(':')[0]);
            int hr2 = Convert.ToInt32(t2.Split(':')[0]);

            int min1 = Convert.ToInt32(t1.Split(':')[1]);
            int min2 = Convert.ToInt32(t2.Split(':')[1]);

            if (hr2 == hr1)
            {
                if (min2 >= min1)
                {
                    i = 1;
                }
            }

            if (hr2 > hr1)
            {
                i = 1;
            }

            return i;
        }
```